# In Visual Studios 2012 What Type Of Project do I Need To Create?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-sdk

I want to create a calculator that can run on a regular computer. However, every time I create a new project it will not run. Instead is says that "The system cannot find the file specified." Last time I had this problem I just needed to create a specific type of project, but I cannot remember which one.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a Win32 Project, as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6765tta0.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't work when I try to make an empty project even if it's Console. Really I'm just trying to make is start out blank were there is no premade code.

Comment: That's really weird. Which VS flavor are you using? Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop?

Comment: I have the Ultimate version.